# Can't Instaniate Class

Tags: java, c#, struct, structure, jna

I'm using a C# dll library in my java code, this library functions is called using jna, some of the parameters of these functions contain Structs, and to create an equivalent parameter in Java I have to create a `static abstract class` which inherits `Structure` class and it must contains all the variables that exists in the struct that I'm trying to create an equivalent to, for more illustration:

**in C#:**

```
struct SDK_AutoConfig {
    int iDay;       
    int iHour;          
    int isec;       
};
```

and there is a function which is like:

```
run_auto_config(int x, SDK_AutoConfig auto)
```

So, to call such function **in Java:**

```
// Declaring the Struct
public static abstract class SDK_AutoConfig extends Structure{
    public int iDay;        
    public int iHour;           
    public int isec;
}

// Instantiating it
SDK_AutoConfig auto = new SDK_AutoConfig() {
    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }
};

// And to call the function
run_auto_config(65, auto);
```

tell here everything is OK, but when there is another `struct` declared as a variable **inside** `the SDK_AutoConfig` `struct`, I can't deal with, what I tried first is to regularly pass it:

```
public static abstract class SDK_AutoConfig extends Structure{
    public int iDay;        
    public int iHour;           
    public int isec;
    public OTHER_STRUCT struct_two;
}
```

but when doing that I get:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Structure field in class Test$1, field name 'struct_two' (class Test$SDK_AutoConfig$OTHER_STRUCT): Can't instantiate class Test$SDK_AutoConfig$OTHER_STRUCT (java.lang.InstantiationException)`

So, I tried to instantiate it first then pass it to the constructor of `SDK_AutoConfig`:

```
OTHER_STRUCT mStruct = new OTHER_STRUCT() {
    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }
};

SDK_AutoConfig auto = new SDK_AutoConfig(mStruct) {
    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }
};

// Then, inside the Class
public static abstract class SDK_AutoConfig extends Structure{
    public OTHER_STRUCT struct_two;
    public DeviceDate(OTHER_STRUCT mStruct){
        struct_two = mStruct;
    }
    public int iDay;        
    public int iHour;           
    public int isec;
}
```

**but I got the same exact Exception.** So, how to solve that?

Comment: Any particular reason that SDK_AutoConfig is an `abstract` class?

Comment: If I remember well, you cannot use JNI nor JNA with C# library. You will need to build a C++ wrapper library.

Comment: @Powerlord idk know the exact reason, this is how I find the way to represent Struct as Class, I'll try to make it regular class and override getFieldOrder myself inside the class

Comment: @ortis yea but now this problem solved, and I'm dealing with the library so well

Comment: @Powerlord I make the both classes NOT abstract and override the Structure method getFieldOrder() inside each one of them and the problem solved, kindly explain what was the problem of what I was doing and the solution in an answer, thanks.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat To be honest, it was just a guess.  I'm not aware of any special rules regarding creating anonymous classes from an `abstract` class.

Comment: @Powerlord #RESPECT your honesty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your anonymous instance creation code into your `Structure` class and remove the `abstract` modifier.  Then you can nest the different structures however you need to.

As for the C# DLL exported API, as long as your method declarations are decorated with `extern "C"` and use only C constructs, they should be exported in a compatible manner and thus usable by JNA.

Comment: great, but what is the meaning of " as long as your method declarations are decorated with `extern "C"`"

Comment: If you compile C++ code the compiler will "mangle" the names of your exported functions.  Adding `extern "C"` around your function definitions and/or header files prevents this mangling and allows you to reference the function names exactly as written.